# scale animation in Fragment Transition

Tags: android, android-animation

How to mention the pivot point for the scale animation in the below xml file. How to specify the pivot being the left edge, right edge and the centre (the default)

```
<objectAnimator
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:propertyName="scaleX"
android:valueType="floatType"
android:duration="500"
android:valueTo="0"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

the I tried the following and it isn't working

```
android:pivotX="1.0"
```

Comment: Have you tried to create an animator-set and add another ```objectAnimator``` with ```android:propertyName``` of ```pivotX```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [link](http://www.qaster.com/q/444150013850308608/Is+there+any+way+to+set+an+the+pivot+of+an+objectAnimator+scale+when+specified+in+xml+I+cant+find+any+example+for+that+chethaase?r=03) it seems this is currently not possible. As suggested in the page we will have to set the transformPivotX property of layout we are animating.